# Unable to install or boot live CD after upgrading my PC

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, gpu-driver

I have recently upgraded my PC with a GTX 1080 Ti graphics card, and an i7 7700k Kaby Lake CPU, now however, I can't boot at all into my Linux partition, nor can I even run a live CD to customize the install to use non-free drivers. I tried on another PC to make sure my media wasn't going bad, and I was able to boot into Linux successfully and run the Live CD. Is there anyway to boot a live CD on this hardware and install Linux? I do also have a DisplayPort out on my motherboard for iGPU if that is necessary.

Comment: Can you describe what have you seen when this happens?

Comment: I'd be looking at problems with the hardware upgrade not OS issues.  Does your mobo recognize the new CPU?  Does the machine boot with the new graphics card removed?  This is likely not a Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Basically, the screen is black and the screen says that USB rejected address 2 and then goes to emergency mode. I am unable to load the system at all. When I know the USB works on my other computers. (Yes, everything is being booted in UEFI mode)

Comment: @jones0610 yes it does recognize the CPU, in fact Windows runs great! Better than I expected, everything is MAXED out at 4k as well. So I know the hardware works. I've had this hardware since May, and waited because I figured there may be some issues with drivers then.

Comment: How about the second part of my suggestion...  removing the new graphics card and using the on-board video port?  If that works you are probably looking at a video driver issue.

Comment: Ubuntu does boot on integrated graphics, is there anyway to get my GPU recognized by Ubuntu then?

Comment: https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/120917

Comment: This answers your question in great detail: https://askubuntu.com/questions/896555/boot-problem-with-nvidia-gtx-1070?rq=1

Comment: Thank you @jones0610 the steps you set out did fix my problem.

Comment: Much obliged :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fully functional GTX 1080 Ti driver is not currently included in the Ubuntu build.

To fix your problem:

- Boot into Ubuntu with your monitor connected to integrated graphics
  port
- Download the GeForce drivers from http://geforce.com/drivers/results/120917
- Reboot and connect the monitor to the new graphics card

Eventually the Ubuntu Team will update the drivers for this relatively new hardware in future builds

NOTE: For those who are working with mobos that do not support integrated graphics, one can always install an old, known good PCI graphics card to get video working temporarily.  These can be obtained very inexpensively at local recycling shops.  This piece of hardware is a very handy troubleshooting item to have around.

Alternately, a much more elegant but slightly more complex workaround can be had using `nomodset`.  Instructions on how to do this can be found at [What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)

Comment: Driver is included, it's the same `nouveau` for all Nvidia chips. That it doesn't support this card properly is different than not being included. And there's no need for the switchroo if using `nomodeset`. In this case OK, it has integrated graphics, so your solution is doable. Now imagine there was no integrated graphics, how would you do it? It would be great if you corrected and improved this answer.