# Xubuntu super slow startup

Tags: xubuntu

computer specs

- cpu: intel i7-7700k kaby lake
- graphics: nvidia gfx 1070
- ram: 16 gb
- hard drive: 500gb solid state drive x1 and 250 gb solid state drive
- wifi card: don't use

xubuntu version: 17.04 (latest ubuntu version)

how can i make my os startup faster. it currently takes 3 minutes and 21 seconds to startup. all other distros ive used normally don't take that long.

i ran the following command

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

prints

```
          9.434s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          1.009s mysql.service
           607ms systemd-resolved.service
           363ms lightdm.service
           362ms dev-sda5.device
           362ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
           300ms apt-daily.service
           115ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            87ms bluetooth.service
            66ms systemd-rfkill.service
            55ms keyboard-setup.service
            55ms networking.service
            51ms snapd.service
            51ms upower.service
            50ms NetworkManager.service
            47ms ModemManager.service
            45ms grub-common.service
            40ms teamviewerd.service
            35ms accounts-daemon.service
            35ms systemd-udevd.service
            34ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            28ms thermald.service
            26ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-781C\x2dCC89.service
lines 1-23
```

i looked at this too

```
dmesg
```

prints

https://pastebin.com/UrVjtMUm

looks like

```
[   92.583751] kauditd_printk_skb: 12 callbacks suppressed
```

is causing the slow startup

more information

```
user@user-desktop:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 13.343s (firmware) + 5.114s (loader) + 2.405s (kernel) + 3min 473ms (userspace) = 3min 21.337s
```

Comment: Please specify your computer

- Brand name and model
- CPU
- RAM (size)
- internal drive (size)
- graphics chip/card
- wifi chip/card
-- and which version of Xubuntu are you running?

Comment: Xubuntu (as well as standard Ubuntu and the other community flavours too) should fly on that computer. Are you using any boot option, for example `nomodeset`? Have you installed a proprietary nvidia driver for the graphics chip/card? Could there be a problem with the `systemd` part of the startup? I don't know if there might be problems with the dual drive (HDD + SSD).

Comment: @sudodus I dual boot with windows 10 and I use grub2 as my bootloader. im using the default boot options. yeah normally linux does. xubuntu is the only distrobution that really struggles to load for me. ive tried elementary os, solus and no issues at all.

Comment: 1. I suggest that you install a proprietary nvidia driver for the graphics chip/card? ; 2. Have you tried the developing version 'Artful Aardvark' to be released as 17.10 in October? http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/376/builds

Comment: @sudodus I haven't. Do I have to completely reinstall my os to upgrade to that version?

Comment: You can install a proprietary nvidia driver into your current system. This link shows a solution rather directly, https://askubuntu.com/questions/896555/boot-problem-with-nvidia-gtx-1070 -- You can also browse the internet with the search string 'askubuntu nvidia 1070' (without quotes) and find several other links, for example one "megalink" with a lot of detailed answers, https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: If you have installed a lot of program packages and spent time on tweaking, you had better install a new system, for example in an another [external or internal] drive or alongside the current system in the internal drive. Upgrading to a developing version will often cause problems.

Comment: @sudodus Yeah I spent a lot of time tweaking xfce  :( if this issue would be regarding my graphics card wouldn't my screen not show up though?

Comment: @sudodus I tried to install the latest nvidia card. installation fails because it says its used by another system (im assuming because im dual booting windows 10 and i have the latest drivers on windows 10 already)

Comment: I think it is another issue, that stops installing the graphics driver. But if you are satisfied with the graphic performance (and the problem is limited to the slow startup) you should look somewhere else. Anyway, let us continue in the automatically created chat room :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65160/discussion-between-sudodus-and-chad-adams).

Answer (score 0):

line 820 seems to be a red herring. Where as lines 821-823 of your dmesg indicates that issue may be apparmor denning "/usr/sbin/mysqld".

To check this look in `/var/log/syslog` via `grep apparmor /var/log/syslog`. Temporarily downgrade apparmor's enforcement by running `sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld` followed by a reboot and evaluate the output of `dmesg`. If the boot time improves restore enforcement by running `sudo aa-enforce /usr/sbin/mysqld`.

To properly configure apparmor for your use of mysqul see the Oracle blog post [AppArmor and MySQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/apparmor-and-mysql). For a deeper look at debugging apparmor see [Ubuntu wiki - DebuggingApparmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor)

Adding an appropriate exception to `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` may solve this portion of the slow boot.

Comment: That command gives me this https://pastebin.com/tYH2iUFz not really sure how to add an exception for that.

Comment: You gotta use  `sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils` to use `aa-complain`command

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't work https://pastebin.com/kJPwk8WV about the same load times. around 3 minutes

Comment: @J.Starnes, You are welcome to the chat room :-)

Comment: Since my answer is wrong. @ChadAdams, Would you add the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze plot > ~/plot.svg`. to your question?